# Operator bool() conflicting with template Type() operator when Type = bool

Tags: c++, c++11, templates

My template operator is conflicting (overloading) with the bool operator when template type is bool. Any way of getting around this? For example, can I somehow "turn off" the `operator T()` when T is assigned to bool?

```
template <typename T = bool>
class MyClass {
public:
    operator bool() const { return false; }
    operator T() const { return t; }
private:
    T t;
};
```

Comment: You could provide a specialized `MyClass<bool>` that avoids the overload conflict.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use SFINAE to disable to `operator bool` when `T` is a `bool` like

```
template <typename T = bool>
class MyClass {
public:
    template <typename U = T, typename std::enable_if<!std::is_same<U, bool>::value, bool>::type = true>
    operator bool() const { return false; }
    operator T() const { return t; }
private:
    T t;
};
```

Another option would be to specialize for `bool` like

```
template <typename T = bool>
class MyClass {
public:
    operator bool() const { return false; }
    operator T() const { return t; }
private:
    T t;
};

template <>
class MyClass<bool> {
public:
    operator bool() const { return false; }
private:
    bool t;
};
```

Comment: A third option is to use a CRTP base class

Comment: OP actually wants to disable `operator T()` so the `template<typename U = T ...` should be moved one line below

Comment: @arnes You get the same thing.  If `T` is a `bool` then using operator T or operator bool doesn't matter

Comment: @NathanOliver According to the code OP shared, it differs, not by declaration but definition.

Comment: @arnes You're right, but the goal was to just disable one of the declarations. Should have made it clear in the question.

Comment: If you'd like a clear explanation of the `typename U = T` necessity, STL gives one in his [old talk](https://youtu.be/dTeKf5Oek2c?t=2106). It goes on for a fair few minutes, with the link timestamp being where the context starts.

Comment: Can also rewrite one of the types to something else with `std::conditional`.

Comment: @T.C. Like `operator std::conditional_t<std::is_same_v<bool, T>, void, bool>() const`?

Answer (score 2):

You can use SFINAE:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

template <typename T = bool>
class MyClass {
public:

    template<typename U = T,typename = std::enable_if_t<!std::is_same_v<U,bool>,void>>
    operator bool() const { return false; }

    operator T() const { return t; }
private:
    T t = true;
};

int main() {
    MyClass mc;
    std::cout << static_cast<bool>(mc);
    MyClass<int> mc2;
    std::cout << static_cast<bool>(mc2);
}
```

Comment: You have to use `enable_if_t` or `enable_if<...>::type` as [`enable_if`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/enable_if) is always defined so your sfinae will never fail.

Comment: I believe your example is simply making the `bool` one less specialized. That is, replacing it with `typename = void` exhibits the same behaviour. The `typename U = T, ...` in the other answer allows for delaying the SFINAE to when this function template is instantiated instead of instantiating `enable_if_t` up front when the class is instantiated.

Comment: @bitmask yes, but after your edit it was just a substitution failure on `MyClass` not just on the method, at least thats how I understand it (https://godbolt.org/z/bwz_z4). Now I understand why the additional `U` is required, and the answer is basically identical to Nathans.

Comment: @chris yes, I fixed it. Still trying to get the hang of SFINAE, I was wondering why `U` is required in Nathans answer. Now I understand